# When going to my domain with www in the url bar I get a double toplevel domain

Tags: .htaccess, server

I am not sure if I am formulating my question correctly, but when I go to www.website.nl I am redirected to: www.website.nl.nl and if I go to www.website.eu I am redirected to www.website.eu.nl

This only happens when I add www. before my domain.

Why does this happen?

This is what I want:

```
all http to https
all www to non www
all .eu (in fact all other topleveldomains other than .nl) to .nl
```

This is how I tried to achieve that:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is matching everything after `www` that includes `.nl` also. You also need another condition to check if domain name is not ending with `.nl`.

You need to replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)(?:\.[^.]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: Thanks now it works for www.website.nl but for www.website.eu I am redirected to www.website.eu.nl